# Filter pandas dataframe on columns if contains *

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where some column values have a astrix *.

I want to remoeve rows that have this.

I have tries this but its not working

```
df.loc[~(df['col_name'].str.contains('*'))]
```

Comment: * is a special character in regex. put a backslash before it : \*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `*` is special regex character add `regex=False` to [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df.loc[~(df['col_name'].str.contains('*', regex=False))]
```

Or escape `*`:

```
df.loc[~(df['col_name'].str.contains('\*'))]
```